# CMake Disable Deleting of Compiled Object

Tags: cmake

Everytime I execute cmake, it will delete all the compiled objects and update the makefiles. How can I disable the deletion of object files and only update of the makefiles?

Thanks!

Comment: CMake should not delete any object files by itself. However, it might be that changes you made to your CMake config require rebuilding all sources.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't ever need to rerun cmake.  Once you've ran it in your build directory, any changes that require updates will be don't automatically when you try to build again.

Comment: @grim: That is not true. You should rerun CMake as often as needed, for example if you want to switch the compiler or the version of an external library.

Comment: @user2799037 Actually rerunning cmake on an external file change typically won't be recognized as the value is in CMakeCache.txt.  However, if you change the value via ccmake or by editing CMakeCache.txt directly, then yes you need to rerun cmake.  However, if you're doing it via ccmake, that would be the configure and generate steps.